# Spark csv file size 2x bigger than with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

As I save data to a single csv file with pyspark I get a 2x bigger file size than if it was after transforming it with `.toPandas()` and then saving it using `to_csv()`.

Any thoughts on what can cause that big discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that can take an effect on size difference.

1. **emptyValue**: By default, Spark's `df.write.csv` will save the null value with wrapping double quote. This increases 2 chars per a single null  value for Spark's `write`. To disable the double quote wrapping, use `.csv(path, emptyValue='')`

```
# Spark write.csv

some value,"",""

# Pandas.to_csv

some value,,
```

2. **Panda's datatype implicit casting.**: When you have nullable integer value in Spark, Pandas will cast integer to float as in Pandas integer is not nullable. This will decrease some characters for Spark's `write`.

```
# Spark write.csv

some value,1000,
some value,,

# Pandas .to_csv

some value,1000.0,
some value,,
```

Other minor things can be Spark won't write header by default while Pandas does. Or Pandas will write `index` value by default whereas Spark doesn't have `index`.

I think there are more things that could affect on how both platform stores data. To observe the difference, I would save the fraction of the data and try look at the file in plain text to see the difference.

Comment: It was indeed `emptyValue` option that caused that big file size discrepancy. Thanks for noticing that!